# Is there a way to discover the original generic argument type of a instance of an Action<in T> delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, contravariance

Is there a way to find the declared generic argument type of an instance of an Action delegate?

In the following code the `WriteGenericArgumentType` function expects and instance of `Action<String>` but because `Action<in T>` allows for contravariance callers of the function are able to call it with `Action<Object>`.

```
static void Main( )
{
    WriteGenericArgumentType( new Action<string>( s => { } ) );
    WriteGenericArgumentType( new Action<object>( o => { } ) );
}

static void WriteGenericArgumentType( Action<string> action )
{
    Console.WriteLine( DiscoverGenericArgumentType( action ).Name );
}

static Type DiscoverGenericArgumentType( Delegate action )
{
    return action.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

However, I need to be able to discover the generic argument type that was defined in the signature of `WriteGenericArgumentType` from the instance of the delegate that is passed to `DiscoverGenericArgumentType`.

When the code runs I get the following output:

```
String
Object
```

But I need it to be:

```
String
String
```

For my purposes I cannot change the signature of `DiscoverGenericArgumentType` and I need that function to return `string` as the type.

I know I can create my own generic delegate type that doesn't allow contravariance but I'm looking for a way to not have to change the signature of the API if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to from inspecting the instance of the [`Action<in T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) passed in.  As you see, it actually *is* an `Action<object>` and there's nothing linking back to the fact that you *wanted* an `Action<string>`.

However, instead of looking at the parameter, you should look at the *signature of the method*.  This will always be `Action<string>` and reflecting/inspecting *that* will always give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was pretty sure that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because you're not changing the object. Consider:

```
static void WriteGenericArgumentType(Action<string> action)
{
    Action<object> action2 = action;
    Console.WriteLine(DiscoverGenericArgumentType(action).Name);
    Console.WriteLine(DiscoverGenericArgumentType(action2).Name);
}
```

You're passing an identical reference to `DiscoverGenericArgumentType` in both cases, so how could it possibly tell what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
static Type DiscoverGenericArgumentType<T>(Action<T> action )
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

It does what you're asking for, but I don't know if you are able to change your method signature to require a specific delegate signature.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can possibly get around this is to wrap the delegate / discover the type at the point I for sure know the type like so:

```
static void Main()
{
    WriteGenericArgumentType( new Action<string>( s => { } ) );
    WriteGenericArgumentType( new Action<object>( o => { } ) );
}

static void WriteGenericArgumentType( Action<string> action )
{
    Console.WriteLine( DiscoverGenericArgumentType( Wrap( action ) ).Name );
}

static Type DiscoverGenericArgumentType( Delegate action )
{
    return action.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
}

static Action<T> Wrap<T>( Action<T> action )
{
    return new Action<T>( o => action( o ) );
}
```